# javascript parseInt detect overflow

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

How to detect if an overflow/underflow is occurred when parsing integer from string using parseInt method?

The approach I thought of is to convert the Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER and Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER to string and check if the string to be checked lies in this range.

Comment: Check it after. `var num = parseInt(str,10); if( num > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER || num < Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER) alert("Overflow/Underflow!");`

Comment: Show some sample examples or code.

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)  **Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER** constant represents the minimum safe integer in JavaScript (-(2^53 - 1)) and **Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER** constant represents the maximum safe integer in JavaScript (2^53 - 1). So It will work

```
var str = '00000010323245498540985049580495849058043';
var num = parseInt(str,10); 
if( num > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
 alert("Overflow!"); 
}
```

Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/91rcnoru/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need [`Number.isSafeInteger()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger)

Also, max int limit is `2^53 - 1`

Also, you can store data in a Float, this way you can avoid the problem altogether. If you application needs to know overflow condition, maybe post the problem statement, there could be a better way to approach it.

Comment: NB: this is an ES6-only function, although there is a polyfill on the MDN page